# How to print the 2nd column of a searched string in a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to search for a file name in a CSV (in column A). If it finds it, then I want to print only the second column (column B), not the whole row.

The CSV is like this:

```
File Name,ID
1234.bmp,1A
1111.bmp,2B
```

This is what I have so far, but it prints both the columns:

```
import os
import csv

f_name = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Python test\Files')[0]

data = []
with open ("test.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

col = [x[0] for x in data]

if f_name in col:
    for x in range(len(data)):
        if f_name ==data[x][0]:
            action = print(data[x])

else:
    print("File not listed")
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. Please create a [mre] illustrating [what code you tried so far](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). For further guidance on how to improve this question, please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Sorry new to site didnt understand posting rule, now changed

Comment: Please also provide sample rows of your CSV. That will allow other people to run your code using the same input, and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You only had a problem with the indexing (and the `print` statement).

After this part of the code:

```py
data = []
with open ("test.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
```

The `data` would now be a list of lists:

```
[ 
  ['File Name', 'ID'], 
  ['1234.bmp', '1A'], 
  ['1111.bmp', '2B']
]
```

In the part where you check the 1st column:

```py
if f_name == data[x][0]:
    action = print(data[x])
```

You printed `data[x]` which would be one row. You need to index it further to access the 2nd column:

```py
print(data[x])     # ['1234.bmp', '1A']
print(data[x][1])  # 1A
```

Furthermore, `print` returns `None`, so `None` would be saved into `action`:

```
>>> action = print("123")
123
>>> print(action)
None
```

You need to assign the value to `action` then `print(action)`:

```py
if f_name == data[x][0]:
    action = data[x][1]
    print(action)  # 1A or 2B
```

You can also further improve the code by eliminating `col`. I understand that it's for checking if `f_name` is in the 1st column ("File Name") of the CSV. Since you are already iterating over each `row`, you can already check it there if `f_name` is in `row`. If it finds it, store the index of that row in a variable (ex. `idx_fname_in_csv`), so that later, you can access it directly from `data`. This eliminates the extra variable `col` and avoids iterating over the data twice.

```py
import os
import csv

f_name = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Python test\Files')[0]

data = []
idx_fname_in_csv = -1  # invalid

with open("test.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
        data.append(row)
        if f_name in row:
            idx_fname_in_csv = idx

if idx_fname_in_csv > 0:
    action = data[idx_fname_in_csv][1]
    print(action)
else:
    print("File not listed")
```

Here `data` would still have the same contents (list of lists) but I used [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the index.

Comment: Thank you  that works better and alot cleaner, this is the first code i am writing ever